# Extraer un bloque de texto delimitado por dos líneas especificas de un fichero

Tags: python, python-2.7, archivo

Tengo un fichero de texto muy extenso del que solo quiero extraer un bloque a otro fichero de texto. El texto a extraer comienza con la siguiente linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y termina con la siguiente linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He escrito el siguiente código y no me imprime en otro fichero de texto la extracción deseada.

```
# Abre un fichero de texto modo lectura
in_file = open("A350-900_SMM10_I4_Exceedance_LCs_Step_7_FS_LHS.f06","r")

# Abre un fichero de texto modo escritura
out_file = open("EXTRACTION_FORCES_CQUADS.txt", "w")

lines = in_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    char_1 = line[0:26]
    char_2 = line[0:1]
    if (char_1 == "      ELEMENT-ID =55100515"):
        while char_2 != "1":
            text = out_file.write(line)

# Cierra el fichero de texto modo lectura
in_file.close()

# Cierra el ficheor de texto modo escritura
out_file.close()
```

Si comento el bucle `while` si hace la extracción de la linea `ELEMENT-ID =55100515`.

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal para que no haga el bucle `while` correctamente y extraiga las lineas que van desde el comienzo del elemento hasta que se encuentra el 1?

---

Fragmento del mega fichero de texto para hacer una prueba

```
    3000556       6.023182E+00  1.023053E+01 -1.074925E+01   -4.197674E-01 -1.215663E-01 -2.054059E-02    5.945688E-03 -8.270144E-02
    3000557       5.842894E+00  1.023645E+01 -1.071378E+01   -4.153232E-01 -1.192223E-01 -6.078959E-03    5.859221E-03 -8.208457E-02
    3000558       5.968817E+00  1.022984E+01 -1.070720E+01   -4.196891E-01 -1.224118E-01 -1.553611E-02    5.919636E-03 -8.245116E-02
    3000559       5.979013E+00  1.022730E+01 -1.068543E+01   -4.205325E-01 -1.236235E-01 -1.621033E-02    5.913686E-03 -8.239029E-02
1    A350-900 HTP ON FUSELAGE (CERTIFICATION LOADS)                          AUGUST  17, 2017  MSC Nastran 11/27/13   PAGE   493
     CMVB00B009 - 10026 - CONFIG 1 - TREF= 20.00DEGC - INTACT WIT                                                                   
0                                                                                                                                   
      ELEMENT-ID =55100515
                                           F O R C E S   I N   R O D   E L E M E N T S     ( C R O D )

                         AXIAL                                                       AXIAL
      SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE                     SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE
   1002600            2.431603E+04   0.0                       1002601            1.622446E+04   0.0
   1002602            1.621741E+04   0.0                       1002603            1.622094E+04   0.0
   1002604            1.620985E+04   0.0                       1002605            1.620762E+04   0.0
   1002606            1.620998E+04   0.0                       1002607            1.621061E+04   0.0
   1002608            1.620382E+04   0.0                       1002609            1.620839E+04   0.0
   1002610            2.431860E+04   0.0                       1002611            1.622685E+04   0.0
   1002612            1.621897E+04   0.0                       1002613            1.622243E+04   0.0
   1002614            1.621159E+04   0.0                       1002615            1.620927E+04   0.0
   1002616            1.621168E+04   0.0                       1002617            1.621233E+04   0.0
   1002618            1.620461E+04   0.0                       1002619            1.621040E+04   0.0
   1002620            5.333795E+04   0.0                       1002621            4.524657E+04   0.0
   1002622            4.524009E+04   0.0                       1002623            4.524282E+04   0.0
   1002624            4.523175E+04   0.0                       1002625            4.522950E+04   0.0

1
```

Comment: Consejo: [No usar readlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading). Nunca. Es ineficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error en la lógica, la comprobación `while char_2 != "1"` desemboca en un ciclo infinito ya que `char_2` siempre va a ser diferente de "1" por definición. Esto se debe a que cuando entras en el `while` la línea es `"      ELEMENT-ID =55100515"`, si en cada iteración del `while` no reasignas el valor de `char_2` esta siempre contendrá `" "`. Debes obtener las nuevas líneas dentro del ciclo `while`, el `for` no itera de nuevo cuando se entra en el `if` (por lo que no se asignan nuevos valores a `line`, `char_1` o `char_2`) mientras no termine el `while`.

Una forma simple de hacer lo que quieres es usar un segundo `for` que continúe iterando sobre el fichero una vez que la primera línea sea detectada:

```
input_file_path = "A350-900_SMM10_I4_Exceedance_LCs_Step_7_FS_LHS.f06"
output_file_path = "EXTRACTION_FORCES_CQUADS.txt"

with open(input_file_path, "r")  as in_file,\
     open(output_file_path, "w") as out_file:

    for line in in_file:
        if line[:26] == "      ELEMENT-ID =55100515":
            for line in in_file:
                if line[0] == "1":
                    break
                out_file.write(line)
            break
    else:
        print("No se encontro el bloque")
```

Si las líneas que delimitan el bloque también han de ser incluidas solo debes modificar un poco el `for`:

```
for line in in_file:
    if line[:26] == "      ELEMENT-ID =55100515":
        out_file.write(line)   
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(line)
            if line[0] == "1":
                break
        break
```

Si tienes más de un bloque y quieres capturarlos todos entonces elimina el segundo `break` y el `else` (las tres últimas líneas).

Comment: FJSevilla Con tu codigo, no me deja abrir el archivo "EXTRACTION_FORCES_CQUADS.txt" por ser demasiado extenso. Podrias decirme porque es eso?

Answer (score 0):

Otra idea es usar la librería [`textfsm`](https://github.com/google/textfsm), creada por Google.

Admito que para este caso particular es "matar moscas a cañonazos", pues es mucho más sencillo ir buscando simplemente las líneas que empiezan de cierta forma junto con un booleano para "recordar" si estamos dentro del bloque a guardar, o fuera de él. No obstante, he decidido añadir esta respuesta como ejemplo de uso de esta biblioteca, que puede ser útil en casos más complicados en los que la información a extraer tenga también una cierta estructura que desees analizar para separar en "campos".

La idea de `textfsm` es que, mediante un fichero aparte, describas qué estructura tiene el fichero que quieres procesar, usando una especie de gramática dependiente del contexto. El formato con que se especifica esta gramática es un tanto farragoso, y se basa en expresiones regulares y en máquinas de estado, pero es muy flexible.

A la librería le pasas tu "esquema" (el fichero antes mencionado), y los datos a procesar, y te devuelve una lista de tuplas con la información que ha encontrado de acuerdo al esquema especificado.

El mayor problema que le veo a esta librería es que, si bien el "esquema" lo lee de un fichero, los datos en cambio los espera en una cadena. Bien es cierto que puedes abrir tu fichero "monstruoso" y leerlo con un simple `f.read()` para tenerlo en una sola cadena, pero esto es altamente indeseable, pues estarás consumiendo tanta memoria como requiera ese fichero de forma innecesaria, puesto que al final el procesamiento se hace línea a línea, por lo que no veo por qué habría de leerse más de una línea de cada vez. Es una mala decisión de diseño por parte de los implementadores de esta librería el no admitir un objeto `file` como parámetro, y obligarte en cambio a pasar un `str`.

No obstante es fácil de arreglar. En el código que sigue implemento mi propia clase (heredando de la que me da `textfsm`) que admite un `file` en vez de una cadena. También muestro cómo sería el "esquema" para procesar tu caso, y cómo mostrar los resultados una vez procesados.

Para hacer el ejemplo más interesante, supongo que tu mega-fichero contiene varios "trozos" interesantes. Cada uno de los trozos delimitado por una línea que contiene lo de "ELEMENT-ID=XXXXXXX" pero con diferente valor de XXXXXX, y que nos interesa guardar todo lo que aparezca entre esa línea y la siguiente que comience por 1, y así *para cada trozo* de este tipo, para al final mostrar todos los trozos hallados, cada uno precedido de una cabecera que muestre su id (el valor de XXXXXXX)

Vamos allá:

```
import textfsm

# Extender la clase para que pueda procesar directamente desde
# un fichero, en lugar de tener que leer antes todo el fichero a memoria
class TextFSMFile(textfsm.TextFSM):

    # Basta añadir un método nuevo a la clase
    def ParseTextFromFile(self, f, eof=True):
        for line in f:
            self._CheckLine(line)
            if self._cur_state_name in ('End', 'EOF'):
                break
        if self._cur_state_name != 'End' and 'EOF' not in self.states and eof:
            self._AppendRecord()
        return self._result


# Plantilla para procesar los datos en este caso, que significa básicamente lo siguiente
#
# 1) Vamos a recoger dos cosas, el "Chunk" (así llamo a todo el texto a recoger)
#    y el Element-id. El texto es cualquier cosa (expresión regular .*)
#    mientras que el ID es una secuencia de dígitos (\d+)
#
# 2) Al empezar ignoramos todo hasta encontrar una línea que comience por ELEMENT-ID
#    Entonces registramos el ID y pasamos al estado Chunk
#
# 3) En el estado chunk, si encontramos una línea que comienza por 1, volvemos al estado start
#    En cualquier otro caso, la línea entera se considera parte del chunk y se registra
template = """#
Value Chunk (.+)
Value Id (\d+)

Start
 ^\s+ELEMENT-ID\s+=${Id} -> Record Chunk

Chunk
 ^1\s+ -> Start
 ^${Chunk} -> Record
"""

# Leemos la plantilla (normalmente hay que leerla de un fichero, pero ya que aquí la tengo
# en una cadena, uso StringIO)
import io
re_table = TextFSMFile(io.StringIO(template))

# Procesamos el fichero y `data` tendrá el resultado
with open("A350-900_SMM10_I4_Exceedance_LCs_Step_7_FS_LHS.f06") as f:
    data = re_table.ParseTextFromFile(f)


# Al terminar, `data` será una lista conteniendo tantos elementos como
# cambios de estado se hayan producido. En cada cambio de estado se genera
# una tupla con el resultado del "Chunk" y del "Id"
#
# Tal como hemos definido la plantilla, cuando registramos un Id, no registramos
# Chunk, y viceversa, por lo que podemos mirar cuándo el segundo elemento
# de la tupla es no-vacío, para saber que se trata de un trozo nuevo
# y entonces imprimir un separador. En caso contrario tenemos el 
# correspondiente chunk
for row in data:
  if row[1]:
      print("\n---------{}-----------".format(row[1]))
  else:
      print(row[0])
```

Le doy como fichero de entrada el siguiente (que es el tuyo al que he añadido más líneas para que tenga un segundo trozo y para que se vea que lo que salga "entre trozos" es ignorado):

```
    3000556       6.023182E+00  1.023053E+01 -1.074925E+01   -4.197674E-01 -1.215663E-01 -2.054059E-02    5.945688E-03 -8.270144E-02
    3000557       5.842894E+00  1.023645E+01 -1.071378E+01   -4.153232E-01 -1.192223E-01 -6.078959E-03    5.859221E-03 -8.208457E-02
    3000558       5.968817E+00  1.022984E+01 -1.070720E+01   -4.196891E-01 -1.224118E-01 -1.553611E-02    5.919636E-03 -8.245116E-02
    3000559       5.979013E+00  1.022730E+01 -1.068543E+01   -4.205325E-01 -1.236235E-01 -1.621033E-02    5.913686E-03 -8.239029E-02
1    A350-900 HTP ON FUSELAGE (CERTIFICATION LOADS)                          AUGUST  17, 2017  MSC Nastran 11/27/13   PAGE   493
     CMVB00B009 - 10026 - CONFIG 1 - TREF= 20.00DEGC - INTACT WIT                                                                   
0                                                                                                                                   
      ELEMENT-ID =55100516
                                           F O R C E S   I N   R O D   E L E M E N T S     ( C R O D )

                         AXIAL                                                       AXIAL
      SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE                     SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE
   1002600            2.431603E+04   0.0                       1002601            1.622446E+04   0.0
   1002602            1.621741E+04   0.0                       1002603            1.622094E+04   0.0
   1002604            1.620985E+04   0.0                       1002605            1.620762E+04   0.0
   1002606            1.620998E+04   0.0                       1002607            1.621061E+04   0.0
   1002608            1.620382E+04   0.0                       1002609            1.620839E+04   0.0
   1002610            2.431860E+04   0.0                       1002611            1.622685E+04   0.0
   1002612            1.621897E+04   0.0                       1002613            1.622243E+04   0.0
   1002614            1.621159E+04   0.0                       1002615            1.620927E+04   0.0
   1002616            1.621168E+04   0.0                       1002617            1.621233E+04   0.0
   1002618            1.620461E+04   0.0                       1002619            1.621040E+04   0.0
   1002620            5.333795E+04   0.0                       1002621            4.524657E+04   0.0
   1002622            4.524009E+04   0.0                       1002623            4.524282E+04   0.0
   1002624            4.523175E+04   0.0                       1002625            4.522950E+04   0.0

1 A350-900 HTP ON FUSELAGE (CERTIFICATION LOADS)                          AUGUST  17, 2017  MSC Nastran 11/27/13   PAGE   493
Esto debe ignorarse
Esto también
      ELEMENT-ID =55100517
   1002614            1.621159E+04   0.0                       1002615            1.620927E+04   0.0
   1002616            1.621168E+04   0.0                       1002617            1.621233E+04   0.0
   1002618            1.620461E+04   0.0                       1002619            1.621040E+04   0.0
   1002620            5.333795E+04   0.0                       1002621            4.524657E+04   0.0
1 Pueden aparecer más cosas tras el 1
Más para ignorar...
```

Y el resultado de ejecutar el script es:

```
---------55100516-----------
                                           F O R C E S   I N   R O D   E L E M E N T S     ( C R O D )
                         AXIAL                                                       AXIAL
      SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE                     SUBCASE            FORCE         TORQUE
   1002600            2.431603E+04   0.0                       1002601            1.622446E+04   0.0
   1002602            1.621741E+04   0.0                       1002603            1.622094E+04   0.0
   1002604            1.620985E+04   0.0                       1002605            1.620762E+04   0.0
   1002606            1.620998E+04   0.0                       1002607            1.621061E+04   0.0
   1002608            1.620382E+04   0.0                       1002609            1.620839E+04   0.0
   1002610            2.431860E+04   0.0                       1002611            1.622685E+04   0.0
   1002612            1.621897E+04   0.0                       1002613            1.622243E+04   0.0
   1002614            1.621159E+04   0.0                       1002615            1.620927E+04   0.0
   1002616            1.621168E+04   0.0                       1002617            1.621233E+04   0.0
   1002618            1.620461E+04   0.0                       1002619            1.621040E+04   0.0
   1002620            5.333795E+04   0.0                       1002621            4.524657E+04   0.0
   1002622            4.524009E+04   0.0                       1002623            4.524282E+04   0.0
   1002624            4.523175E+04   0.0                       1002625            4.522950E+04   0.0

---------55100517-----------
   1002614            1.621159E+04   0.0                       1002615            1.620927E+04   0.0
   1002616            1.621168E+04   0.0                       1002617            1.621233E+04   0.0
   1002618            1.620461E+04   0.0                       1002619            1.621040E+04   0.0
   1002620            5.333795E+04   0.0                       1002621            4.524657E+04   0.0
```